# Gulp AssertionError - Sass Dependancies

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-watch, gulp-sass

Trying to run through this tutorial to get a beginner's feel:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nusgoj74a3Y

Currently getting this error when running gulp, any ideas?:

gulpfile.js

```
'use strict';


//dependancies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');


// - SCSS/CSS

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';


gulp.task('compile_scss', function() {

  gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));

});

gulp.task('watch_scss', function() {
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, ['compile_scss']);
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

Output

```
assert.js:269
    throw err;
    ^

AssertionError [ERR_ASSERTION]: Task function must be specified
at Gulp.set [as _setTask] (/Users/ss/Desktop/reactTest/my-app/node_modules/undertaker/lib/set-task.js:10:3)
at Gulp.task (/Users/ss/Desktop/reactTest/my-app/node_modules/undertaker/lib/task.js:13:8)
at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/ss/Desktop/reactTest/my-app/gulpfile.js:34:6)
at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:702:30)
at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:713:10)
at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:612:32)
at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:551:12)
at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:543:3)
at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:650:17)
at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:20:18)
```

A little stumped, any help appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You are using gulp 4, the terminology has changed to

```
'use strict';


//dependancies
var gulp = require('gulp');
var sass = require('gulp-sass');
var minifyCSS = require('gulp-clean-css');
var uglify = require('gulp-uglify');
var rename = require('gulp-rename');
var changed = require('gulp-changed');


// - SCSS/CSS

var SCSS_SRC = './src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss';
var SCSS_DEST = './src/Assets/css';


gulp.task('compile_scss', function() {

  gulp.src(SCSS_SRC)
  .pipe(sass().on('error', sass.logError))
  .pipe(minifyCSS())
  .pipe(rename({ suffix: '.min' }))
  .pipe(changed(SCSS_DEST))
  .pipe(gulp.dest(SCSS_DEST));

});

gulp.task('watch_scss', function() {
  gulp.watch(SCSS_SRC, gulp.series('compile_scss'));
});

gulp.task('default', ['watch_scss']);
```

Basically running files is more robust. You can now negate plugins like runSequence as this has all of that functionality.

essentially what you can do is go

```
gulp.task('build', function (callback) {
    runSequence('runFirst', ['ranTogether1','ranTogether2'], 'ranLast'), callback
});
```

to

```
gulp.task('build',
  gulp.series('runFirst', gulp.parallel('ranTogether1', 'ranTogether2'),'ranLast'),
  function() {...}));
```

[More info here](https://fettblog.eu/gulp-4-parallel-and-series/)

Comment: Getting closer, have a new error now:

Error: watching ./src/Assets/scss/**/*.scss: watch task has to be a function (optionally generated by using gulp.parallel or gulp.series)

Comment: Sorry, I went back and changed your snippet. Check my original answer, as it has been updated. :D

Comment: I received another Assertion Error :/

Comment: have you tried replacing the `('stuff",'stuff')` with brackets instead like `['stuff','stuff']` idk I am sticking with gulp 3 you've frightened me

Comment: Can you make this into a repo and ensure a branch stays in this state? I'd love to figure this one out since it is fighting so hard